# trying to install react-native-drawer but get errors

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add **react-native-drawer** to my project.
but when I run:

```
npm install --save react-native-drawer
```

I get:

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-native@0.41.1
└── react-native-drawer@2.3.0 

npm WARN rn-drawer@1.1.3 requires a peer of react-native@^0.4.0 but none was installed.
```

I tried several actions people recommended like erasing my **node_modules** directory, or upgrading **npm** to the latest, or trying to install this module in a different project, but nothing helped. I can hardly believe that what is being implied here is that I simply have a version of react-native too new for this module.

my react native version is:

```
react-native-cli: 1.3.0
react-native: 0.41.1
```

my npm version is: 4.3.0

thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you package.json looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you accidentally installed [rn-drawer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-drawer) on your 
package.json.

Just run:

```
 npm uninstall --save rn-drawer
```